# Severe input lag for mouse and keyboard

Tags: macos, performance, steam

I have a small problem with my mac. I'm currently restricted to game on my Macbook Pro (13"/2017/i5/iGPU iris 640/16gb) with macOS 10.15.7.

I can't do Bootcamp on this machine for disk-space reasons.

My idea was to run steam/dota on this machine, which seems totally doable as multiple tests/videos online show (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKcO2WytIMo). I don't expect ultra graphics details or high fps, but a playable experience.

Unfortunately, when playing the game, the framerate is "bearable" (20-25 fps, even without ANY action) - but even in the lobby the fan of my Macbook goes up to max speed.

I play the game at the lowest possible resolution with lowest possible details. Launch options are `-vulkan -nojoy -noaafonts -novsync -console -novid`. switching to the `opengl-renderer` doesn't change anything. all background programs closed.

Even worse - and that's the topic of this post - mouse and keyboard inputs are extremely (!!!) laggy. Individual clicks or key presses are NOT REGISTERED AT ALL! All controls feed laggy and "muchy", nice gameplay is impossible. Still, the game produces a "stable" 20-25 fps - so I assume there is some other reason for inputs being "dropped" here

Is there any way to fix this input lag or at least how to narrow down the issue?

Apparently, it IS possible to play this game on a Mac like mine, so the question is whats wrong with my machine?

Comment: I would first try an offline game instead of an online game to eliminate potential network problems. If the offline game works well I would rather check the used network instead of your computer.

Comment: Botmatches (offline) show the same problem